# NetBSD/FreeBSD and TP-Link TL-WN727N: Second encounter

Tags: drivers, freebsd, netbsd

First part at  [NetBSD and TP-Link TL-WN727N (Atheros AR9271 or Ralink RT5370)](https://superuser.com/questions/975564/netbsd-and-tp-link-tl-wn721n-atheros-ar9271-or-ralink-rt5370)

So, I've installed NetBSD 7 and device shown again as `ugen`(ugein, lol).

```
ugen0 at uhub4 port 8 
ugen0: Mediatek 802.11 n WLAN, rev 2.01/00, addr 2
```

Then I'm installed FreeBSD 10.2 and `ugen` again.

`usbconfig` gives me `ugen4.3: <product 0x7601 vendor 0x148f> at usbus4, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH(480Mbps) pwr=ON (90ma)`

So, what's next? Buying new dongle is a last thing, which I'll make.

UPD: NDIS driver not works.

Answer (score 1):

This device has no support by any driver, including **NDIS**.
Problem caused just because new version of chip presenting self to system as **Mediatek**, not as **Ralink**.

So, anything can be done now — writing to developers. 
I'll give this stick to my friend with Windows and then shall research ways to use  3G-modem directly or Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD:

I think your device might be supported by the run(4) driver. Maybe only the usb ID are missing in the FreeBSD driver. Try posting to the freebsd-usb@FreeBSD.org mailinglist.

If it is not supported, you might use the windows driver together with the ndis(4) wrapper.